# Selecting some lists from a list of lists

Tags: scheme, nested-lists

I would like to have some lists from a list of lists under a certain condition. For example:

```
`((a w) (e w))`
```

from

```
`((a w) (e w) (i u) (o u))`
```

where the condition is to have 'w in the second position.

My code

`(filter (andmap (equal? (cdr lst) 'w)) 'lst)`

with

`(define lst '((a w) (e w) (i u) (o u)))`

is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific than "is not working" when you're describing a problem.

Comment: Start with writing a predicate that works with one list element – that is, a procedure `p` such that `(p '(a w))` is `#t` and `(p '(i u))` is `#f`. Then use that. (`andmap` is of no use here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not quote the list: `'lst` is not the same as `lst`. And to access the second element, use `second` (if that's not defined, use `cadr` instead). With `cdr` you get the *rest* of the list (which is another list), not its second *element*. Oh, and `filter` expects a `lambda` as its first argument, not `andmap`. This is what I mean:

```
(define lst '((a w) (e w) (i u) (o u)))
(filter (lambda (sl) (equal? (second sl) 'w))
        lst)
=> '((a w) (e w))
```