# C# Select some lists in many lists that look like a list

Tags: c#

Sorry if the header made you confused.
This thread looks similar header but that is actually different [Selecting some lists from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375293/selecting-some-lists-from-a-list-of-lists).

I want to **Select some lists in many lists that look like a list**
Sample:

```
    // data source
    List<List<int>> sources = new List<List<int>>();
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 2, 99, 3, 4, 5, 6});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 3, 99, 2, 4, 5});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){5, 4, 3, 2, 1});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 2, 4, 5, 6});
    sources.Add(new List<int>(){1, 2, 69, 3, 4, 5});

    // the list that we want to find lists similar to this
    List<int> current = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

The list contain not-important element, can be ignored. **Updated! In the case its elements are not appeared in current**:

```
    List<int> flexible = new List<int>() {99, 66, 123123, 2};// <= updated!
```

The function I want to write:

```
    void FilterA(List<int> current, List<List<int>> sources, List<int> flexible) {}
```

How to make `FilterA` output these list (**Lists chosen**)? Printing functions are not required.

```
Lists chosen
    1 2 3 4 5 // exactly the same !
    1 2 3 4 5 6 // same first 5 elements, the rests are not important
    1 2 99 3 4 5 6 // 99 is in flexible list, after ignored that is 1 2 3 4 5 6
    // Updated! Ignore 99 because it is not in list current
    

Lists ignored
    1 2 3 4 // missing 5 in current
    1 3 99 2 4 5 // 99 is in flexible list, after ignored that is 1 3 2 4 5
    5 4 3 2 1 // wrong order
    1 2 4 5 6 // missing 3 in current
    1 2 69 3 4 5 // 69 is not in flexible list
```

Thank you very much!

**--- Updated ---**
If elements in list `flexible` appeared in list `current`, they must not be excluded.
The answer of @Sweeper is nice.
p/s: In the case not any element of `flexible` appear in `current`, @TheGeneral 's answer is great, runs great performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a method that determines whether *one* list (`candidate`) should be chosen:

```
public static bool ShouldChoose(List<int> candidate, List<int> current, List<int> flexible) {
    int candidateIndex = 0;
    foreach (int element in current) {
        if (candidateIndex >= candidate.Count) {
            return false;
        }

        // this loop looks for the next index in "candidate" where "element" matches
        // ignoring the elements in "flexible"
        while (candidate[candidateIndex] != element) {
            if (!flexible.Contains(candidate[candidateIndex])) {
                return false;
            }
            candidateIndex++;
        }

        candidateIndex++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can do a `Where` filter:

```
var chosenLists = sources.Where(x => ShouldChoose(x, current, flexible)).ToList();


foreach (var list in chosenLists) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update after clarification**

The premise is, remove flexible with `Except`, `Take` *n* to then compare with `SequenceEqual`.

<sub>*Note : All three methods have linear time complexity O(n)*</sub>

```
var results = sources.Where(x =>
   x.Except(flexible)
      .Take(current.Count)
      .SequenceEqual(current));
```

**Output**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 99, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

**[Full demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EPH81X)**

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0)

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

[Enumerable.Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0)

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
> sequence.

[Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether two sequences are equal according to an equality
> comparer.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah its a good point, and i didn't put too much thought into it apart from its most minimalist requirements according to the output, though you could be right, and this would become a little more complicated

Comment: Sorry I should tell that more clearly. Think like `1 3 99 2 4 5` or `1 2 69 66 4 5` must not be chosen. I had updated the question. About the `HashSet` that is awesome, thank you!

Comment: @sweeper is your comment still relevant?

Comment: @KhangDinhHoang Can `flexible` contain things that are in `current`? If it can, then `Except` will remove those too, making some lists that should be chosen, not chosen.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault for not thinking about that detail. @Sweeper is right. `flexible` can contain elements in `current`. Today I learned a lot from @Sweeper (not because the codes but he is so careful). @TheGeneral thank you, your solution is awesome, runs great performance. Please update the answer one more time and don't delete your current solution. May be other people will find it fit their case.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var results =
    sources
        .Where(source => source.Except(flexible).Count() >= current.Count())
        .Where(source => source.Except(flexible).Zip(current, (s, c) => s == c).All(x => x))
        .ToList();
```